# Recursion and If-statements

Tags: recursion, conditional

So I'm trying to write a recursion module in *Mathematica* (specifically for strassen multiplication but this doesn't matter). My issue is I don't really know how `If` statements work in *Mathematica* and if I can program recursive functions in the same way as I once learned in Java.

My (incomplete) code is

```
Strassen[A_, B_, p_] := 
Module[
{A11, A12, A21, A22, B11, B12, B21, B22, Return, 
originalDim = Dimensions[A][[1]], dim, extraDim, cutoff = 40, 
PaddedA, PaddedB},

//IMPORTANT STUFF
If[originalDim <= cutoff, 
Return = mm[A, B, p]
];
//IMPORTANT STUFF


//UNIMPORTANT STUFF
dim = If[NumberIsPowerOfTwo[originalDim], originalDim, 
MinimalPowerOfTwo[originalDim]];
PaddedA = PadRight[A, {Automatic, dim}];
PaddedA = PadRight[Transpose[PaddedA], {Automatic, dim}];
PaddedB = PadRight[B, {Automatic, dim}];
PaddedB = PadRight[Transpose[PaddedB], {Automatic, dim}];
A11 = PaddedA[[1 ;; dim/2, 1 ;; dim/2]];
A12 = PaddedA[[dim/2 + 1 ;; dim, 1 ;; dim/2]];
A21 = PaddedA[[1 ;; dim/2, dim/2 + 1 ;; dim]];
A22 = PaddedA[[dim/2 + 1 ;; dim, dim/2 + 1 ;; dim]];
B11 = PaddedB[[1 ;; dim/2, 1 ;; dim/2]];
B12 = PaddedB[[dim/2 + 1 ;; dim, 1 ;; dim/2]];
B21 = PaddedB[[1 ;; dim/2, dim/2 + 1 ;; dim]];
B22 = PaddedB[[dim/2 + 1 ;; dim, dim/2 + 1 ;; dim]];

]
```

Now the point of my function is that at some point I will call it again to do some multiplications on smaller matrices. Eventually when my matrices are small enough I want them to enter the `If`-statement and return the value "Return", but before that I want it to just skip that part and execute the code below.

Is this how if statements work in *Mathematica*?

Comment: did you see [that](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html)?

Comment: Also, you are using Return as a variable (by assigning a value to it). Return is a function and should not be used as a variable. Try `?Return`.

Comment: it is not advisable to start your own symbols with caps.  Particulartly `Return` conflicts with a built in.

Comment: Start simple! Write a much simpler little example recursive function with some Print statements and try to figure out how recursion and If and Mathematica work.

Comment: yes i read through that quite a few times. I don't really understand what it means that the function returns "Null". Will the module return Null and exit as soon as the if statement is false? Or will it continue? And how does the semi-colon affect the output of the If statement? Will it return "Return" if it's true or the output be suppressed?

Good point about Return, will change that

Comment: Do you know how I could return my "return" value? The semi-collon surpresses the output yes?

Comment: The semi-colon on the `If` statement isn't the problem. (In fact, you need it.) Remove `Return` from the list of variables, and change the `If` statement to `If[originalDim <= cutoff, Return[mm[A, B, p]]]`. In addition, I am assuming that you want an output from this function even when the `If` statement is *not* satisfied. If I am right, what is that output supposed to be?

Comment: No, the only way i want output is if I enter the if statement, the rest of the function calls the Strasser function again until the if-statement is entered

Comment: But you need an output of the function `Strassen` that will act as input for the recursive call of `Strassen`, don't you?

Comment: As far as the semicolon goes, [this post on the meaning of the semi-colon in *Mathematica*](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18617#18617) is tangentially related to your questions.

Comment: yes but this is how recursive functions work, the function will keep calling the Strassen function and then use the output from the if-statement for all the previous occurences of Strassen (I'm 99% certain this made zero sense but my english isn't the best, sorry)

Comment: I think I see (yes: I was thinking about a different recursion construct I think). Anyway, I think my suggestion above should fix the problem.

Comment: yes, it would indeed :) thanks for the link as well, that looks really helpfull!

Comment: Instead of the `If` you can create separate functions and use pattern matching: `Strassen[A_List /; Dimensions[A][[1]] < 40, B_, p_] := ..
 `